# ONTO and 1-1 for F(x,y)

Tags: functions

For the function $f: {\rm I\!R}^2 \rightarrow {\rm I\!R} $ where $F(x,y)$ = $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 +dx +ey$ it's unclear to me how to determine which parameters ($a,b,c,d,e$) for $f(.)$ are onto and/or 1-1. For a function to be onto, there needs to be an $x$ in the domain for every $y$ in the co-domain. I think I understand this for a function $f(x) = y$, but how then do I apply this to a function $f(x,y) = z$?

It's my understanding that tor a function to be 1-1, it needs to pass the horizontal line test. I've tried graphing the function and playing with different parameter different values to see if it makes visual sense. If I give parameters $a,b$ or $c$ values, the surface takes on a saddle like shape where points on the $x$ axis intersect with more than one point on the $z$ axis. 
whereas, if I leave them zero and give parameters $d$ or $e$ values, the surface becomes flat, and the horizontal line test seems to pass.

[Flat Surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZpyB.jpg)

[Curved Surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGnaB.jpg)

This makes sense to me visually, but I would like to know how to determine which parameters are injective and/or surjective more formally?

Comment: To test if $F$ is 1-1 (or injective), you really have to use a "horizonal plane test" (since the domain of $F$ is $\mathbb{R}^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z = f(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey$

The function is surjective (onto) if for every $z$ in $\mathbb R$ there is some $(x,y)$ pair that maps to z.

Clearly we can find values of $f(x,y)$ such that $z \le 0$  e.g. $a,c > 0 , b,d,e = 0$

For what values could it be onto?  Look at $b^2 - 4ac.$ What is this expression in the quadratic formula, and why might that be relevant here?

The function is injective (into, 1-1) if $f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2,y_2) \implies (x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2).$

Fix some value of $z$ is the set of $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = z $ a curve (or a line) or a singular point?

If it a curve, it can't be injective.

Update:

Suppose we set $z$ equal to some constant $k$

$a,b,c = 0 \implies dx + ey = k$ is a line.

Otherwise:

$b^2 - 4ac > 0 \implies ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey = k$ is a hyperbola.
$b^2 - 4ac = 0 \implies ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey = k$ is a parabola.
and $b^2 - 4ac < 0 \implies ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey = k$ is an ellipse.

In all cases $f(x,y)$ cannot be 1-1.

What about onto?

If $f(x,y) = k$ describes a sequence of hyperbola, will it be defined for all values of $k$?

What about if it a sequence of ellipses or a parabola?

Another way to think about it...

If $b^2 - 4ac > 0$ then $(ax^2 - bxy + cy^2)$ can be factored into something of the form $(px + qy)(rx + sy).$
If $b^2 - 4ac = 0$ then $(ax^2 - bxy + cy^2)$ is a perfect square i.e. $(\sqrt a x + \sqrt cy)^2.$
If $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ then $(ax^2 - bxy + cy^2)$ can be written as the sum of two squares -- something of the form $(px + qy)^2 + (rx + sy)^2.$

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong @DougM. : using B2−4ac (the discriminant), different values of a,b & c, will result in either positive, negative or zero values. If negative, there aren't any real values that will map (x,y) to z, if zero there will be one (x,y) combination mapping to z and if positive, there will be two combinations. Does this mean that a value of zero relates to being 1-1 and a positive value relates to being onto?

Comment: I have added updated my answer to give a little bit more explanation regarding $b^2 - 4ac$

Comment: So where a,b,c = 0 where dx + ey = k, all values of k can definitely be defined. I also think that where k is a hyperbola or parabola this will be true, but I don't think this is the case where k is an ellipse. When I graph these functions, the ellipse is the only one that doesn't extend forever

Comment: Can it is possible that $x^2 - y^2 = -1$  but not $x^2 + y^2 = -1$

Comment: $x^2−y^2=−1$ is possible, but $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ is not possible. Then the perfect square is not onto either, since negative values of z are unobtainable?

Comment: That is it.  If $b^2 - 4ac > 0$ the function is onto.

Comment: So fixing z to a constant and using the discriminant allows for a straight forward approach to this problem in $R^2$. Thank you very much for your help :)